# Pandas: Convert a DataFrame into a Series when index is Year-Month and columns are Day

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks similar to the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Y_M':['201710','201711','201712'],'1':[1,5,9],'2':[2,6,10],'3':[3,7,11],'4':[4,8,12]})
df = df.set_index('Y_M')
```

Which creates a dataframe looking like this:

```
        1  2  3   4
Y_M                
201711  1  2  3  4
201712  5  6  7  8
201713  9  10 11 12
```

The columns are the day of the month. They stretch on to the right, going all the way up to 31.  (February will have columns 29, 30, and 31 filled with NaN).
The index contains the year and the month (e.g. 201711 referring to Nov 2017)

My question is: How can I make this a single series, with the year/month/day combined? My output would be the following:

```
Y_M                
20171001    1
20171002    2
20171003    3
20171004    4
20171101    5  
20171102    6
20171103    7
20171104    8
20171201    9
20171202   10
20171203   11
20171204   12
```

The index can be converted to a datetime. In fact I think it would make it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` and then combine `datetimes` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `timedeltas` by
[`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df = df.stack()
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(0), format='%Y%m') + \
           pd.to_timedelta(df.index.get_level_values(1).astype(int) - 1, unit='D') 
print (df)
2017-10-01     1
2017-10-02     2
2017-10-03     3
2017-10-04     4
2017-11-01     5
2017-11-02     6
2017-11-03     7
2017-11-04     8
2017-12-01     9
2017-12-02    10
2017-12-03    11
2017-12-04    12
dtype: int64

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2017-10-01', '2017-10-02', '2017-10-03', '2017-10-04',
               '2017-11-01', '2017-11-02', '2017-11-03', '2017-11-04',
               '2017-12-01', '2017-12-02', '2017-12-03', '2017-12-04'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Last if necessary `strings` in `index` (not `DatetimeIndex`) add [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y%m%d')
print (df)
20171001     1
20171002     2
20171003     3
20171004     4
20171101     5
20171102     6
20171103     7
20171104     8
20171201     9
20171202    10
20171203    11
20171204    12
dtype: int64

print (df.index)
Index(['20171001', '20171002', '20171003', '20171004', '20171101', '20171102',
       '20171103', '20171104', '20171201', '20171202', '20171203', '20171204'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Stack is exactly the function I needed! Thank you @jezrael!

Answer (score 2):

Without bringing `date` into it.

```
s = df.stack()
s.index = s.index.map('{0[0]}{0[1]:>02s}'.format)
s

20171001     1
20171002     2
20171003     3
20171004     4
20171101     5
20171102     6
20171103     7
20171104     8
20171201     9
20171202    10
20171203    11
20171204    12
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Wow. This is a great way of doing it! Allows one to do this with non-date values too. 
I don't quite understand it though. Inside `index.map()`, you pass it a string which dictates what it maps. It accesses the hierarchical index "0," levels 0 and 1. But I have no idea what the `:>02s` is, and why this also works with 2-digit values in the original "day" columns.

Comment: `pd.Index.map` takes a callable and passes each index value to it.  In this case, the index is a multiindex.  So each value passed to the callable is a tuple.  Knowing that, I concocted a string formatting callable that handles it.  You can do many funky things with string formatting and I can't cover it all here but what I did was to say that I want the first element of the tuple `{0[0]}` in the front and the second element of the tuple `{0[1]}` in the back.  However, I added some alignment magic to it.  `{0[1]:>02s}` says to align the string to the right with a buffer of 2 and fill with `0`.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! This is awesome.